# Create webservice from jar file that used maven

Tags: java, web-services, maven, jar

I am developing a project(Spring+Hibernate+Maven+Intellij Idea for develop) without any application server such as tomcat. Now I don't know  how create Web Service from my project to use it in other projcets ?! My Question is how to create Web Service from jar file that created by maven?

Comment: What do you mean: `How to create a Web Service from JAR file?` A web service is usually a war file. Can you elaborate that a little bit more?

Comment: my project create a Jar file and do not create war file, in maven:

    <groupId>com.cityid</groupId>
    <artifactId>common</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>

Comment: Where would you like to deploy the app? From the other comments I'm reading on that you don't have one. Have you implemented your own Servelet Container ?

Answer (score 0):

You can [embed Jetty](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Embedding_Jetty) in your application or use [Restlet](http://restlet.org/discover/features) which provides an embedded server.

Simply add them as dependencies and have all the resolved jars on your classpath (the maven assembly plugin may help you package your application)

Comment: I don't understand how to embed jar files(springframwork....) that used in my project! moreover i dont have any web application server (tomcat or ..) !

Comment: I know you do not have any servlet container, that is the reason why I am telling you to embed jetty or use Restlet. You need a server for your web services. Maybe you should start by reading the Maven documentation, then read the Jetty Embedded or Restlet documentation.